# How to get the primary key of the Users table to comments table foreign key using eloquent in Laravel 7 or 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, has-many

i want to get or join the users table into my **comments** table. but i dont have a idea how to do that
i used **hasMany** to get all the **comments** table to **posts** . and i want to join the **users** table to

here is my Model Posts

```
namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Posts extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        public function comments(){
            return $this->hasMany(Comments::class,'posts_id');
        }
    }
```

here is my **PostsController** i used **hasMany**  with **posts** and **comments** tables

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Posts;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return Posts::with('comments')->get();
        return view('welcome',['authors'=>$authors]);
    }
}
```

the output of my **PostsController** using **hasMany**

```
   [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "post": "im in relationship now",
    "comments": [
            {
            "posts_id": 1,
            "comments_id": 1,
            "users_id": 1,
            "comments": "sweet"
            },
            {
            "posts_id": 1,
            "comments_id": 2,
            "users_id": 2,
            "comments": "grats"
            },
            {
            "posts_id": 1,
            "comments_id": 3,
            "users_id": 3,
            "comments": "wow"
            },
            {
            "posts_id": 1,
            "comments_id": 4,
            "users_id": 4,
            "comments": "grats dudes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "post": "im graduate now",
    "comments": [
            {
            "posts_id": 2,
            "comments_id": 5,
            "users_id": 5,
            "comments": "stay strong"
            },
            {
            "posts_id": 2,
            "comments_id": 6,
            "users_id": 6,
            "comments": "sweets"
            },
            {
            "posts_id": 2,
            "comments_id": 7,
            "users_id": 7,
            "comments": "ayiee"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

on the output you see the comments has a users_id i want to join the users table to grab the information of that table like name and username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Comment.php model add this relation

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class );
    }
```

in for loop of comments in view

```
{{$comments->user->name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i already solved this

```
return $posts = Posts::with(['user', //users who created and posted
        'comments' => function($user) {
            $user->with('users'); //users who commented 
 }])->get();
```